# Problem copying formulas from cell above in VBA

Tags: excel, vba

New to VBA and am trying to insert a row below including formulas contained within the cells of the row I am copying. I have figured out how to copy a row and insert it below the last row within the table using the code below:

```
 maxRow = Application.Match(Application.Max(Range("A:A")), Range("A:A"), 0)
    Cells(maxRow + 1, 1).EntireRow.Insert
```

but this won't copy the formulas. I've tried to use the following:

```
Dim lastrow As Long

    lastrow = Sheets("Summary Info").Range("A999").End(xlUp).Row
    Range("B159:I159").Copy Destination:=Sheets("Summary").Range("A" & lastrow)
```

but keep getting an error.

Any help is appreciated

Comment: What's the error message? Why does one line have `Sheets("Summary Info")` and the next have `Sheets("Summary")`?

Comment: Run-time error'1004': Application-defined or object defined error - I renamed the sheet to "Summary" from "Summary Info" and forgot to change in both places

Comment: And the differing sheet names? Is that on purpose?

Comment: No, I've corrected it that but get the same error